# Customizing search bar in iPhone application Development

Tags: iphone, ios, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller, uisearchbardelegate

In my application I have to add a search bar at the head of the tableview. I am able to add the searchbar but problem is without adding default search bar of ios can i add my customize search bar?? I am giving an image to see what types of search bar will be there...

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can subclass the `UISearchBar` and override the `layoutSubviews` method :

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
   UITextField *searchField;
   NSUInteger numViews = [self.subviews count];
   for(int i = 0; i < numViews; i++) {
      if([[self.subviews objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) { //conform?
        searchField = [self.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
      }
   }
   if(!(searchField == nil)) {
       searchField.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
       [searchField setBackground: [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"] ];
       [searchField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
   }

   [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

Also you can :

```
//to clear searchbar backgraound
- (void) clearSearchBarBg
{
    for (UIView *subview in theSearchBar.subviews) 
    {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarBackground")]) 
        {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
            break;
        }
    }
}

//display showSearchButtonInitially in a keyboard 
- (void)showSearchButtonInitially
{
    UIView * subview;
    NSArray * subviews = [theSearchBar subviews];

    for(subview in subviews)
    {
        if( [subview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]] )
        {
            NSLog(@"setEnablesReturnKeyAutomatically");
            [((UITextField*)subview) setEnablesReturnKeyAutomatically:NO];
            ((UITextField*)subview).delegate=self;
            [((UITextField*)subview) setEnabled:TRUE];
            ((UITextField*)subview).borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually i have got you what do you want to say but if you explain it then it will too much helpful for me...thanks for quick reply.

Comment: I will accept your answer if you explain it actually i am beginner at iPhone application Development...so please explain, i have to solve it quickly.

Comment: the above code is accessing the subviews of search bar such as text filed, background of text field .... simple

Answer (score 2):

Look for [Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html) DOC for UISearchBar

[image]

You have bunch of methods there to get whatever you want

You can get UITextView Inside the search bar by

```
UITextField *textField = [searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:2];

if ([textField isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
    //Do your customization
}
```

Again look for [AppleDoc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html) for UITextField. You have bunch of methods for that also.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah definitely. You can make your custom search bar (which is a sub-class of `UIView`) and add it as subview to the `tableHeaderView`.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[searchBarDesign.subviews objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
```

here searchBarDesign is my searchBar name.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better just set all properties of UISearchBar when it is loaded.

```
@interface MySearchBar : UISearchBar

@end


@implementation MySearchBar

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self myInitialize];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)awakeFromNib

{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self myInitialize];
}

-(void)myInitialize
{
    self.backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];

    for (UIView* subview in self.subviews) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            //customize text field
            UITextField* textfield = (UITextField*) subview;
        }
    }
}

@end
```