# UISearchbar Programmatically iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Is there any possiblity to make the UISearchbar programmatically to resemble the same like the image below??

[image]

I have no idea to proceed with, pls help me out!

Comment: Yes you can manage. You can also use textField and customize it.

Comment: so i can just use customized textfield & do search process???

Comment: we can do stuff using this.

Comment: using which? can i have any example regarding or link it'll be useful to go in the right path..

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24574/objective-c-discussion come to room for discussion

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24578/discussion-between-preethi-and-nirav)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a background image:

```
[[UISearchBar appearance] setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bgimage.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Or you can subclass the UISearchBar and override the layoutSubviews method like was explained in this thread:

[Customizing search bar in iPhone application Development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654967/customizing-search-bar-in-iphone-application-development)